# Get random number based on probability

Tags: javascript

I was wondering to get a random number with two decimal places based on probability for example:

```
40% to get number from 1-10
20% to get number from 11-20
30% to get number from 21-30
10% to get number from 31-35
```

Comment: Generate a random number and use a number wheel.

Comment: You can use "Weighted random numbers" as search term. "Probability" normally refers to a distribution (normal, poisson, etc...)

Comment: You could research how to do it, try to implement it and come back if you get stuck then.

Comment: Searching SO for "weighted random number [javascript]" finds lots of hits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function Prob(){
    var rnd = Math.random(),
        rnd2 = Math.random();
    if(rnd<0.4) return (1 + Math.floor(1000 * rnd2)/100);
    else if(rnd<0.6) return (11 + Math.floor(1000 * rnd2)/100);
    else if(rnd<0.9) return (21 + Math.floor(1000 * rnd2)/100);
    else return (31 + Math.floor(500 * rnd2)/100);
}
```

You need two random numbers, so I calculate them at the start. I then use the if-else loops to cycle through your 40%, 20%, 30% and 10% (adding them up as I go). Note: Math.random returns a number between 0 and 1. Then for each catagory I use the SECOND random number to get in the range you have said - floor it to make sure it is an integer and add the starting number of each range. Note: the range of your last one is just 5.

I should explain, you must use two random numbers, otherwise the range of the second number would be dependent on which category you are in.

I have to do the 1000 * rnd2 in the floor and then divide by 100 outside to get the 2 decimal place you ask for.

Comment: Looks good. Just needs to return a float with two decimal places.

Comment: Jecoms - you do need two random numbers. I have explained more in my answer. Otherwise the range random part would be dependent on which category you are in. Also why do I need a float with 2 dec places?

Comment: It was stated in the question.

Comment: Yep, you are right. I will modify it.

Comment: It working good but I need to have 2 decimal place `0.00`

Comment: The modification with the 1000*rnd2 in the floor and the /100 outside should do the trick. Jecoms was right.

Comment: Thank you for help

Answer (score 3):

Rewind's solution is great and specifically tailored to OP's quesiton. A more re-usable solution might be:

```
function getNumber(probabilities){
    var rnd = Math.random();
    var total = 0;
    var hit;
    for(var i = 0; i < probabilities.length; i++){
      if(rnd > total && rnd < total + probabilities[i][0]){
           hit = probabilities[i]
      }
      total += probabilities[i][0];
    }
    return Number((hit[1] + (Math.random() * (hit[2] - hit[1]))).toFixed(2));
}

var number = getNumber(
  [
    //chance, min, max
    [0.4, 1, 10], 
    [0.2,11,20], 
    [0.3,21,30], 
    [0.1,31,35]
  ]
);

console.log(number);
```

The function will take an array with the probabilities, for each probability you specify the chance, the minimum value for that chance, the maximum value for that chance. It will return a number with two decimals.

https://jsfiddle.net/x237w5gv/

Answer (score 0):

I guess this

```js
var get1120 = _ => ~~(Math.random()*10)+11,
    get2130 = _ => ~~(Math.random()*10)+21,
    get3135 = _ => ~~(Math.random()*5)+31,
          a = [get3135,get1120,get1120,get2130,get2130,get2130],
        fun;
result = (fun = a[~~(Math.random()*10)]) ? fun() : ~~(Math.random()*10)+1;
console.log(result);
```

might do it;