# Generate a random boolean 70% True, 30% false

Tags: javascript, random

I have the following function that generates a random boolean.
choose_direction: function () {

```
 var random_boolean = Math.random() >= 0.5;
    if (random_boolean) {
        trade.call()
        prev_trade.goingUp = true
        console.log('Trade: CALL!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
    } else {
        trade.put()
        prev_trade.goingUp = false
        console.log('Trade: PUT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
    }
}
```

However, I need the distribution to be unfair. More specifically, I want the output to be 70% of the time true and 30% of the time false.

Comment: IMO just checking that `Math.random() >= 0.7` should do the trick :)

Comment: @atomrc you mean `>= 0.3` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get random number based on probability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39731632/get-random-number-based-on-probability)

Comment: technically speaking, this isn't random, for a number of reasons :-)

Comment: It's called pseudo-random https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Instead of `>= 0.5` you just need `< 0.7`:

```
var random_boolean = Math.random() < 0.7;
// 70% this will be true, 30% false
```

As @plasmacel commented, `Math.random()` returns a value between `0` and `1` (including `0`, but not `1`: `[0, 1)`), so therefore we do `< 0.7`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider one thing. Math.random() gives you a pseudo-random number.

Try this function:

```
function randomTest(triesCount) {
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < triesCount; i++){
        sum += Math.random();
    }
    return sum / triesCount;
}
```

if you try it with different triesCount parameters the results will be:

- randomTest(100) - 0.5189474703446081
- randomTest(100) - 0.5189474703446081
- randomTest(1000) - 0.4973368682657417
- randomTest(10000) - 0.5001058467610172
- randomTest(100000) - 0.4987280984186288
- randomTest(1000000) - 0.4999987387801045
- randomTest(10000000) - 0.49998292815655454
- randomTest(100000000) - 0.500079160302315

So as you can se the results go to 0.5 which means this is not a random number generated here.

Although the answer to your question will be

> var random_boolean = Math.random() >= 0.3;

as Ionică Bizău said.

But keep in mind that it is pseudo-random number!

Comment: It is pseudo random in a sense that it only generates numbers between 0 and1. True randomness generation of number would imply generating numbers between -infinity and +infinity which impossible for both human and computer to emulate

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version I made with `typescript`. Can easily remove the variable types to turn this into `javascript`.

```
//Usage
let randomBoolean = randomPercentForTrue(70)

export function randomPercentForTrue(percentage: number): boolean {
    return randomNumber(1, 100) <= percentage
}

export function randomNumber(minValue: number, maxValue: number): number {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxValue - minValue + 1)) + minValue
}
```

These methods are heavily tested with various use cases. Here are test cases with mocha:

```
it('randomPercentForTrue with 95% accuracy', function() {
    let results0: boolean[] = []
    let results1: boolean[] = []
    let results2: boolean[] = []
    let results3: boolean[] = []
    let results4: boolean[] = []
    let loopAmount = 10000
    for(let i = 0; i < loopAmount; i++) {
        results0.push(randomPercentForTrue(0))
        results1.push(randomPercentForTrue(25))
        results2.push(randomPercentForTrue(50))
        results3.push(randomPercentForTrue(75))
        results4.push(randomPercentForTrue(100))
    }

    let resultTotals = Array(5).fill(0)
    for(let i = 0; i < loopAmount; i++) {
        resultTotals[0] += results0[i]
        resultTotals[1] += results1[i]
        resultTotals[2] += results2[i]
        resultTotals[3] += results3[i]
        resultTotals[4] += results4[i]
    }

    expect(resultTotals[0]).to.be.closeTo(0, 0)
    expect(resultTotals[1]).to.be.closeTo(loopAmount * 25 / 100, loopAmount * 25 / 100 / 20)
    expect(resultTotals[2]).to.be.closeTo(loopAmount * 50 / 100, loopAmount * 50 / 100 / 20)
    expect(resultTotals[3]).to.be.closeTo(loopAmount * 75 / 100, loopAmount * 75 / 100 / 20)
    expect(resultTotals[4]).to.be.closeTo(loopAmount, 0)
})
```